# Why is Notes column in Project Tasks is grayed out?

Tags: sharepoint-server, tasks

I am using SharePoint server 2010.

I have created a 'Project Tasks' page. I can see the Gnatt chart the default set of columns.

I would like to add a column where people can add notes or text related to that task. I added the 'Notes' column by doing the following -

List --> List Settings --> Columns --> Create Column.

I chose 'Multiple Lines of text' from column type.

I can now see the column in my Project Tasks page. But when i go to edit it, it is greyed out. Wont let me write any text to it.

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by 'Inline Editing' being disabled by default. If I use the standard form to edit these rows, it works, and I am able to add text to these rows.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple line of text field which has Rich Contents enabled is not editable in DataSheet View.

I think this is locked because the HTML content can mess up with DataSheet view.

Workaround is to convert the column into a Plain Text field.

Open List Settings -> Click on Notes Field ->  UnCheck `Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)`

Comment: The column has been set to 'Plain Text'. I have attached a picture above to show all the settings for this column.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the multi-line text type is a rich text that is disabled by design

- For SharePoint 2010 so you need to select a **plain text** as text type to can be able to edit columns in datasheet view .
- For SharePoint 2013 you can select either a **plain text** or **Enhanced rich text** as text type to can be able to edit columns in edit view .

[image]

Hope it helps you

Comment: Column is set to Plain text. Please new screenshot attached above.

Comment: Make sure that the site has added to compatibility view , local intranet sites in IE,